# Symlinks and File Redirection

Tags: c++, fstream

In C++, how would I go about checking if a file that we are opening is being redirected through Symlinks? Here is my file opener handler:

```
 f=fopen(addr.c_str(), "rb");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You tagged it c++, why not use `fstream` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use stat(), it will automatically follow the symlink.  If you use fstat(), the symlink will have already been followed as the file will have been opened to get the file descriptor.

lstat() is preferable over stat() and fstat() in this particular case as it does not follow the symlink.  After calling lstat(), then call open().  However, there is a race condition problem inherent in this method; another process/thread/task could come along between the call to lstat() and open() and change the file to a symlink.

Fortunately, there is a solution to this race condition.  When opening the file with open(), you may be able to use the flag O_NOFOLLOW.  This will tell open() not to follow symlink if there is one.  However, you will still need to know if the file you opened was a symlink (but not followed) or not.  To do this, use the file descriptor returned from open() with fstat().

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You want to look into [`lstat`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/lstat.html) and check the `st_mode` field of the [`struct stat`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sysstat.h.html) for `S_IFLNK`.