# Why is the lstat() function failing?

Tags: c, file

I'm having problem understanding how lstat() in c actually works. I have already read the following documentation but still have some problems understating how lstat() really works and why doesn't it work the way i
I use it.
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/sys_stat.h.0p.html
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=functions-lstat-get-status-file-symbolic-link
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lstat.2.html
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lstat.3p.html
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fstatat.3p.html

Basically what I want to do is write a program similar to the command find, that list all files/directories and subdirectories. I want to use lstat() to check if a file is a symbolic link and if so skip it. The st_mode gives information about the file type.

```
#includes ...

void error_handling(char* msg){
      perror(msg);
      exit(1);
} 


void print_cwd(){} //prints the current working directory
void print_path(char* path){} //prints the current path

void handle_path(char * path) {

  int success = chdir(path);
  if (success != 0) {
    if (errno == ENOTDIR || errno == ENOENT) {
      return; // OK, just ignore non-directory entries for recursion
    } else {
      error_handling("chdir");
    }
  }

  DIR *current_dir = opendir(".");
  if (current_dir == NULL) {
    error_handling("opendir");
  }
  struct dirent *current_dirent;
  while (1) {
    errno = 0;
    current_dirent = readdir(current_dir);
    if (current_dirent == NULL) {
      if (errno != 0) { // readdir doesn't change errno on success, hence, it should be zero
        error_handling("readdir");
      }
      break;
    }
    char *name = current_dirent->d_name;
    if (strcmp(name, "..") == 0 || strcmp(name, ".") == 0) {
      continue;
    }
    print_path(current_dirent->d_name);
    handle_path(current_dirent->d_name);
  }
  closedir(current_dir);

/* it doesn't matter where i call lstat() it always falis, be it before opening the directory or anywhere else. As soon as this is calledit fails
  struct stat buf;
  int s = lstat(path, &buf);
  if(s != 0)
    error_handling("lstat");
*/

  chdir("..");
}
```

It fails with the following error: **lstat: No such file or directory**
As described here https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lstat.2.html in the return value section, these function return 0 on success and -1 on error.
According to this post I found on here [Symlinks and File Redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237439/symlinks-and-file-redirection) you should call lstat() after you call open(). Still fails with the same error

Comment: Have you tried calling `lstat` *before* you call `chdir`? Or only after?

Comment: calling ```lstat``` after the the second ```chdir``` and before the first did indeed work. but i don't understand why?

Comment: Because the path is to the directory you change into. Once you changed into that directory, the path isn't valid anymore. Unless there's a subdirectory with the exact same name.